# createMany on createMany in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

So, I have 2 one to many relationship, first is `questionnaire` and `question` where `question` is `belongsTo` `questionnaire`. And the second one is `question` and `answer` where `answer` is `belongsTo` `question`. I have 2 arrays that look like this:

```
$questionData = [
    ['question' => 'Question 1'],
    ['question' => 'Question 2']
];

$answerData = [
   ['answer' => 'Good'],
   ['answer' => 'Meh']
];
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is insert the `$questionData` first using `createMany` method and then followed by `$answerData` so my `answer` table will kinda look like this:

```
id   question_id   answer
1    1             Good
2    1             Meh
3    2             Good
4    2             Meh
```

I've tried with something like this:

```
$question = $questionnaire->question()->createMany($questionData);
$question->answer()->createMany($answerData);
```

And it gave me `Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::answer does not exist.` error. Any idea on how to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`createMany` [returns](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php#L1105) an [iterable](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.iterable.php) (in this case an array) of all of the objects that were created. In your case it will return an array containing all of the questions it created.

You can loop through each of them using `forEach` and call `createMany` on each of them:

```
$questions = $questionnaire->question()->createMany($questionData);
foreach ($questions as $question) {
   $question->answer()->createMany($answerData);
}
```