# How to use createMany

Tags: laravel

I am new to Laravel and I have many arrays that I want to insert in database with `createMany()` this is my code what I have done so far:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'order_number' => 'required',
        'client' => 'required',
        'products' => 'required',
        'amount' => 'required',
        'description' => 'required',
    ]);
    for($i = 0; $i < count($request->products); $i++)
    {
        $values[] = [
            'order_number' => $request->order_number,
            'client' => $request->client,
            'products' => $request->products[$i],
            'amount' => $request->amount[$i],
            'description' => $request->description,
        ];
    }
    dd($values);
   Order::createMany($values);
    return redirect('/')->with('msg', 'Order Saved successfully!');
}
```

I saw on Internet and documentation examples like this:

[createMany on createMany in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63701197/createmany-on-createmany-in-laravel)

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-methodhttps://)

But I don't understand how it works.

This is how the values show up:

[image: Print Data]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you using Laravel 8+ try to use upsert

```
Order::upsert($values,'order_number');
```

Comment: im using Laravel 9

Answer (score 1):

`createMany()` only works on relationships, what you should be using is `insert()`

So `Order::insert($values);`

You can read more on insert here: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#insert-statements

---

Because you want the timestamps to be updated then what you can do is this:

```
foreach($values as $value){
   Order::create($value);
}
```

---

Since you are modifying the array before creating, you can always just add the `updated_at` and `created_at`

```
$values[] = [
   'order_number' => $request->order_number,
   'client' => $request->client,
   'products' => $request->products[$i],
   'amount' => $request->amount[$i],
   'description' => $request->description,
   'updated_at' => now(),
   'created_at' => now(),
];
```

Comment: when i use `insert` method the timestamp comes null unless i write it on the code here get time now

Comment: so basically only insert method works in this situation?

Comment: You are correct. The proper way is to use insert, but if you want to have proper timestamps, then you can just use a foreach loop and then create on by one :) But since you are modifying the data array, you can always inject the updated_at and created_at there :D